# laravel passport bearer token not working

Tags: laravel

Hi I am trying to get the passport login working using the bearer token  in laravel. the alert shows a token from localstorage.
I have the following javascript code which in the laravel project is in :
/public/js folder:

```
    var token   = localStorage.getItem('token');
    alert( token );
    var jsonp_url = "http://localhost/site1/api/get_data?callback=?"
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'jsonP',
        url: jsonp_url,
        jsonp: true,
        headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token},
        success: function(result) {
                alert("DATA");
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        },
        error: function(result) {
            alert("ERR");
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }
    });
```

then in a external javascript file I include it as follows:

```
<script src="http://localhost/site1/public/js/api_users.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The API route in api.php is as follows:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/get_data', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    try {
                return response()->json([ 'stuff' => 'some data'], '200' )->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
    }
    catch( \Exception  $e ) {
                        Log::error('Error - ajax_srch_postcode'.$e);

                        return Response()->json([ 'error' => 'Error cannot proceed!!'], 500 ); // Status code here
    }
});
```

So the code returns a status 200 message but is dropping to the error handler code in the ajax code, rather than the result bit...any ideas??

Comment: if I change the route FROM: //Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/get_data', function ( Request $request) {
TO:  Route::get('/get_data', function ( Request $request) {  I get the JSON data returned -- but it is not protected is it??

Comment: I think it has something to do with the api route redirecting to login ( auth route) -- instead of returning a JSON message saying unathenticated...not sure why yet